# Flutter how to do foreach inside a list widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a set of menus. I want one menu to appear only to users whose role is admin.  I have saved the roles in shared preference.

Code:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    getName();
  }

  void getName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    myList = prefs.getStringList("roles");
    myList.forEach((w){
      if(w == "ROLE_ADMIN"){
      
      }else{

      }
    });
    setState(() {});
  }



 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          _createHeader(),

          _createDrawerItem(
              icon: Icons.home,
              text: 'Dashboard',
              onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home')),
          _createDrawerItem(
              icon: Icons.timer,
              text: 'Admin Temperature \n Check-in',
              onTap: () =>
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/temperatureadmin')),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }

 Widget _createDrawerItem(
      {IconData icon, String text, GestureTapCallback onTap}) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(icon),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: Text(text),
          )
        ],
      ),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }
```

How can I add a foreach loop inside the List widget to only show the Admin Temperature \n Check-in menu to users who are admin only?